# Swift compiler segmentation fault with generic recursive function

Tags: ios, swift, generics, recursion

I've run into an interesting issue with the Swift compiler, which seems to be caused by a very simple generic function. I've got a workaround, but I'd really like to understand what the underlying issue is.

In my app I have a requirement to fade in some UICollectionViewCells in a given order, sequentially, with a slight overlap between the animations. 
I've implemented this using the methods below. The `revealCells` method takes an array of cells. If the collection is empty, it simply returns. Otherwise it animates the fade-in on the first cell in the array, and then waits a certain amount of time before making a recursive call to itself, passing all the cells except the one it just animated.

Code below:

```
func revealCells(cells:[UICollectionViewCell],animationTime:NSTimeInterval,overlap:Double) {
  if cells.count > 0 {
    let firstCell = cells.first
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstCell?.alpha = 1.0
        let timeMinusOverlap = animationTime - overlap
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(timeMinusOverlap * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          self.revealCells(self.cdr(cells),animationTime: animationTime,overlap: overlap)
        })
      })
    }
  }
}

//Returns the collection passed into the function with its first element removed
//i.e the traditional LISP cdr function

func cdr<T>(input:[T]) -> [T] {
  var rVal = [T]()
  if input.count == 1 {
    rVal.append(input.first!)
  } else {
    rVal = [T](input[1...input.count-1])
  }
  return rVal
}
```

All this works fine in the simulator. But when I try to archive the build, the swift compiler crashes with the message `Swift Compiler Error Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault 11`. My setup is Xcode 6.3.1 (iOSSDK 8.3), and my min deployment target is 8.3.

Fixing the problem is trivial - if I just replace the code inside the `dispatch_after` with:

```
 let newCells = [UICollectionViewCell](cells[1...cells.count-1])
 self.revealCells(newCells,animationTime: animationTime,overlap: overlap)
```

the problem goes away. So it seems to be something to do with the generic function, or possibly something block related.

Stack trace is:

```
0  swift                    0x000000010105ba18     llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000010105bef4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8725ef1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000000000000f _sigtramp + 2027557135
4  swift                    0x00000001021a98cb llvm::AsmPrinter::EmitFunctionBody() + 4379
5  swift                    0x000000010116c84c llvm::ARMAsmPrinter::runOnMachineFunction(llvm::MachineFunction&) + 220
6  swift                    0x0000000100d81d13 llvm::MachineFunctionPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 99
7  swift                    0x00000001024d5edf llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 495
8  swift                    0x00000001024d60cb llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 43
9  swift                    0x00000001024d658f llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 975
10 swift                    0x0000000100a09b41 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::Module*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 4369
11 swift                    0x0000000100a09cb3 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 51
12 swift                    0x0000000100945687 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 6647
13 swift                    0x0000000100943ae6 main + 1814
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8a46b5c9 start + 1
```

(a long list of program arguments, which are mostly the names of file being compiled)

```
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module    '/Users/tolleyr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseTestQuiz-fgnfjkxxlyqfnrfrfntgtsjnrcfv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ParseTestQuiz/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ParseTestQuiz.build/Release-iphoneos/ParseTestQuiz.build/Objects-normal/armv7/QuizQuestionViewController.o'.
2.  Running pass 'ARM Assembly / Object Emitter' on function '@_TFC13ParseTestQuiz26QuizQuestionViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_'
```

(the last part enabled me to figure out what code was causing the problem). The command being run was `CompileSwift normal armv7`

I'm going to file a radar for this, since the compiler itself is crashing , but thought I'd post it here in case anyone has an idea of what might be going on, or has run into the same issue.

Comment: Make sure to test later versions of Xcode. Many, many compiler crashes have already been fixed. Any compiler crash is a bug in Swift. Often they mean you *also* have a syntax error in your code. Moving to a later version of the Swift compiler will often tell you the error, and then you can backport the solution to the older compiler if you need to.

Comment: Also getting a segmentation fault on my generics, was fine in Xcode 7 Beta 5, moved to Xcode 7 Beta 6, and can't compile. Our generics are much more woven throughout our parsing classes and so can't easily work around. @RobNapier  it's actually might be a problem introduced in a newer version of LLVM/Xcode